# How do I grant root access to Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

Im using Pycharm 5.04. whenever I need to `install package requirements` in a `requirements.txt` file, I have to enter my root password for each package, that is, many many times if the file has many requirements. How can I solve this I'm on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually cause when you are using the system python for your project's environment. You can create a virtual environment from within pycharm following the steps below:

> Pulled from  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/creating-virtual-environment.html

1. Open the Settings dialog box, and then open the Project Interpreters page.
2. Click cog wheel next to the Project Interpreter field, and choose the option Create VirtualEnv.
   2.1. Create Virtual Environment dialog box opens.
3. In the Create Virtual Environment dialog box, do the following:

   - In the Name field, type the name of the new virtual environment, or accept the suggested default name.
   - In the Location field, specify the target directory, where the new virtual environment will be created, or accept the suggested default location.
   - From Base interpreter drop-down list, select one of the configured Python  interpreters, which will be used as the base for the new virtual environment.
   - If the desired base interpreter is missing in the drop-down list, you can locate  it manually by clicking  browseButton.
   - If you want the site-packages of the base interpreter to be visible from the virtual environment, select the check box Inherit global site-packages. If you leave this check box cleared, the new virtual environment will be completely isolated.
   - You can make this virtual environment available to all projects, by selecting the check box Make available to all projects.
   - Click OK to apply changes and close the dialog box.